# Detecting the outer edge of an object in an image

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to extract the outer edge of the attached image. Could you please advice me how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Is it about Mathematica at all?

Comment: Yes I have tried it with Mathematica. The problem is that I don't know how to extract  the outer contour only.

Comment: @Florin In the future, it would be really great if you could include what you have done, as a code snippet.  This is an interesting problem; what is this shape for?  Interfaces between liquids?

Comment: @Florin If your question has been answered, please consider marking one of the answers as Accepted!

Comment: Hi drN! OK! It is indeed an interface. However I am a real beginner. Not yet able to share codes. I am learning the ABC.

Comment: Ignore my stupid question. Got it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming the question is about Mathematica...

```
SelectComponents[
 MorphologicalPerimeter@MorphologicalBinarize@i, "Count", -2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Carl !! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 11):

One method to isolate the outer edge in Mathematica is to use the `EdgeDetect[]` function.

Note: I hand tuned the program for this image (it will not work for other images).

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wc6Q.jpg"];
EdgeDetect[img, 1, .43] - EdgeDetect[img, 1, .45]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Conor !! I have tried with EdgeDetect but I did not know about using it this way. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ConorCosnett Always nice to see another Irish Mathematica user!

Comment: Haha thanks, unfortunately we are a rare breed. (Everyone seems to be wasting their time, reinventing the wheel, in MATLAB and C in these parts.)

Comment: @ConorCosnett Tell me about it. If you're in Dublin feel free to give me a shout and we can grab a coffee/pint and chat about how much better us Mathematica users are than our peers 

Comment: Certainly. I couldn't turn down an opportunity to do that .

Comment: @ConorCosnett https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89202/discussion-between-carl-lange-and-conor-cosnett

Answer (score 9):

An approach that doesn't need too much tweaking is to use LocalAdaptiveBinarize followed by the selection of the largest component:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wc6Q.jpg"];
object = ColorNegate@DeleteSmallComponents[LocalAdaptiveBinarize[img, 30]]
MorphologicalPerimeter@SelectComponents[object, "Count", -1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bill! Thank you very much!